# what is the best way to store XML in oracle? (CLOB vs XMLTYPE vs VARCHAR)

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xmltype

in oracle we can store XML files in different types of variables like `XMLTYPE` or `CLOB` or `VARCHAR2`. I want to know what is the difference between them and benefits of any of them?
 and is there any difference between `XMLTYPE` column in regular table and `XMLTYPE` table for storing XML files in a table?

Comment: Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/toc.htm ) has answers for all questions you ask.